# Vue.js behaves weird in production mode, development is ok

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

My Vue app works correctly in development mode but not in production mode.
The only difference is in package.json:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --mode production"
```

vs

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development"
```

I build with `npm run build` and use apache2 as Webserver.

The essential parts are as following:

VuePageList.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="entry in listEntries">
      <VuePageListEntry :key="entry.VueKey" :Payload="entry" />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import VuePageListEntry from '@/VuePageListEntry.vue';
import { ListEntry, EListEntryType } from '@/ListEntry';

@Component({
  components: {
    VuePageListEntry,
  },
})
export default class VuePageList extends Vue {
  get listEntries(): ListEntry[] {
    const ListEntries: ListEntry[] = [];
    let rgEntry = new ListEntry('Group 1', EListEntryType.Header);
    ListEntries.push(rgEntry);
    let rEntry = new ListEntry('Report 11', EListEntryType.Report);
    rgEntry.SubEntries.push(rEntry);
    rEntry = new ListEntry('Report 12', EListEntryType.Report);
    rgEntry.SubEntries.push(rEntry);
    rgEntry = new ListEntry('Group 2', EListEntryType.Header);
    ListEntries.push(rgEntry);
    rEntry = new ListEntry('Report 21', EListEntryType.Report);
    rgEntry.SubEntries.push(rEntry);
    return ListEntries;
  }
}
</script>
```

VuePageListEntry.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="Payload">
    <div
      v-if="Payload.EntryType === EListEntryType.Header"
      style="background: orange; margin-top: .25rem;"
    >
      {{ Payload.Name }}
    </div>
    <div
      v-else-if="Payload.EntryType === EListEntryType.Report"
      style="background: yellow;"
    >
      {{ Payload.Name }}
    </div>
    <div v-else style="background: red;">
      {{ 'Unknown Type ' + Payload.EntryType }}
    </div>
    <template v-for="entry in Payload.SubEntries">
      <VuePageListEntry :key="entry.VueKey" :Payload="entry" />
    </template>
  </div>
  <div v-else>X</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { ListEntry, EListEntryType } from '@/ListEntry';

@Component
export default class VuePageListEntry extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Object as () => ListEntry, required: true })
  public Payload!: ListEntry;
  public EListEntryType = EListEntryType;
}
</script>
```

ListEntry.ts:

```
export enum EListEntryType {
  SubHeader = 'SubHeader',
  Report = 'Report',
  Header = 'Header',
}

export class ListEntry {
  public Name: string;
  public EntryType: EListEntryType;
  public SubEntries: ListEntry[] = [];

  public get VueKey(): string {
    const vk =
      this.Name +
      '_' +
      this.EntryType +
      '_' +
      this.SubEntries.reduce((str, x) => {
        return str + '_' + x.VueKey;
      }, '');
    return vk;
  }

  constructor(name: string, type: EListEntryType) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.EntryType = type;
  }
}
```

The SubEntries are displayed in development mode but not in production mode.
The resulting html in production mode is:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div style="background: orange none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin-top: 0.25rem;"> Group 1 </div>
      <vuepagelistentry payload="[object Object]"></vuepagelistentry>
      <vuepagelistentry payload="[object Object]"></vuepagelistentry>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="background: orange none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin-top: 0.25rem;"> Group 2 </div>
      <vuepagelistentry payload="[object Object]"></vuepagelistentry>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What can be the cause of such behavior?
And what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix. `vue-property-decorator` is the "culprit":

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/102

It works when I explicitly specify a name for the recursive component in VuePageListEntry.vue:

```
@Component({ name: 'VuePageListEntry' })
export default class VuePageListEntry extends Vue {
```